# SharePoint 2010 Document Library Link to A Folder in File System

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

Is it possible to map the file system folders in Document Library folders? I don't want to add link but I just want to map folders in a server different from SharePoint2010 server to a document library. Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could recreate this model by faking out the users. Use Search, and index your file location. Use a Search Results web part to display a list of the files in the folder. This would give a peek into the folder.

Alternatively, you can use a 3rd party solution. I think Bamboo has one.

HTH